# How to Add Custom Columns to DataGridView after Loading from DataTable

Tags: c#, datagridview

My Windows Form App has a DataGridView on it with a could of Textbox fields.  When data is entered into a Textbox field the DataGridView is reloaded.

I query my SQL server, and generate a DataTable from the results.
I then load those results into the DataGridView.
I want to add several additional columns to the DataGridView.
I have added them in my code below, however, when the function is called again, it adds another set of the columns to the already existing DataGridView definition.  If I refresh the data multiple times it adds another set each time.

If I add them before the DataGridView is loaded from the DataTable then the columns are added first, which is not what I want.

Should I wipe the DataGridView somehow before loading?
Do I need to check to see if the column already exists before creating?

What's the best option here?

```
private void FillTable(string location, string supplier, string item) {
        string sql = "";
        string connString = "Data Source=B606SQLERP;Initial Catalog=P21DCImport17;Integrated Security=true;";

        // If ONLY Location is entered
        if (location != "" && supplier == "" && item == "") {
            MessageBox.Show("Only Location");
            sql = "SELECT " +
                    "      location_id AS 'Location', " +
                    "      supplier_id AS 'Supplier', " +
                    "      item_id AS 'Item', " +
                    "      recommended_qty_to_order AS 'Rec Qty'" +
                    "  FROM PorgReqs  " +
                    "  WHERE location_id = @LocationID " +
                    "  ORDER BY supplier_id, item_id";

        }

        // If ONLY Supplier is entered
        if (location == "" && supplier != "" && item == "") {
            MessageBox.Show("Only Supplier");
            sql = "SELECT " +
                    "      location_id AS 'Location', " +
                    "      supplier_id AS 'Supplier', " +
                    "      item_id AS 'Item', " +
                    "      recommended_qty_to_order AS 'Rec Qty'" +
                    "  FROM PorgReqs  " +
                    "  WHERE supplier_id = @SupplierID " +
                    "  ORDER BY location_id, item_id";

        }

        // If ONLY Item is entered
        if (location == "" && supplier == "" && item != "") {
            MessageBox.Show("Only Item");
            sql = "SELECT " +
                    "      location_id AS 'Location', " +
                    "      supplier_id AS 'Supplier', " +
                    "      item_id AS 'Item', " +
                    "      recommended_qty_to_order AS 'Rec Qty'" +
                    "  FROM PorgReqs  " +
                    "  WHERE item_id = @ItemID " +
                    "  ORDER BY location, supplier_id";

        }


        // Creates Connection, Sets Variables in Connection and tries to load table
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString)) {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

            // Sets Variables
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LocationID", txtLocation.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SupplierID", txtSupplier.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemID", txtItem.Text);

            // Opens Connection
            conn.Open();

            try 
            {
                // Creates Reader Object
                SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();


                // Fill the list box with the values retrieved
                if (sqlDataReader.HasRows) {
                    // Create DataTable
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                    // Add Columns to DataTable
                    dt.Columns.Add("Location");
                    dt.Columns.Add("Supplier");
                    dt.Columns.Add("Item");
                    dt.Columns.Add("Rec Qty");
                    dt.Load(sqlDataReader);

                    gridData.DataSource = dt;

                    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn txtAddlQty = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
                    txtAddlQty.Name = "AddlQty";
                    txtAddlQty.HeaderText = "Add'l Qty";
                    txtAddlQty.Width = 75;
                    gridData.Columns.Add(txtAddlQty);

                    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn txtFinalQty = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
                    txtFinalQty.Name = "FinalQty";
                    txtFinalQty.HeaderText = "Final Qty";
                    txtFinalQty.Width = 75;
                    gridData.Columns.Add(txtFinalQty);

                    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cboAction = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
                    cboAction.Name = "Action";
                    cboAction.HeaderText = "Action";
                    cboAction.Items.AddRange("Buy", "Transfer", "Not Buy");
                    cboAction.Width = 75;
                    gridData.Columns.Add(cboAction);

                    DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn chkApprove = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
                    chkApprove.Name = "Approve";
                    chkApprove.HeaderText = "Approve";
                    chkApprove.Width = 50;
                    gridData.Columns.Add(chkApprove);

                    gridData.Columns["Location"].Width = 60;
                    gridData.Columns["Supplier"].Width = 60;
                    gridData.Columns["Item"].Width = 125;
                    gridData.Columns["Rec Qty"].Width = 75;

                    // Adds default value to the Action column
                    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in gridData.Rows) {
                        row.Cells["Action"].Value = "Buy";
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    } // End Function
```

Comment: You are going to want to split that into 2 methods - a one time setup method to add the columns and the other to fetch the data.  Rather than add columns (which you are doing as strings only) you can let the DGV create the columns and go thru and just change the headers.  I am not sure many of the columns will auto update between the datatype and SQL alias

Comment: I ended up adding a check to see if one of the columns exist.  Interesting though, it puts the columns in a different order the second time.

Comment: Did you define columns using GUI or programatically? You loose the order and custom header text and more, if you provide "nothing" to the datagridview.DataSource. You need either to restore the settings or provide the same valid datatable without rows instead of nothing, in case of empty result. And as your core problem - I would split data and DGV definition and apply the up-to-date definition at the time of filling. One way is to use just datasource datatable as suggested, but you can also create a shadow datatable or List (of List Of()) to store properties for each column.